# Office Powerpoint Ribbon item and mouseover event?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am trying to create a Ribbon menu in the Powerpoint that has some similar feature to the standard one. My question is : Is it possible to create an Office Powerpoint Ribbon menu like the standard built-in menu as follow, and catch the mouse over event on each ribbon item?

- Open menu "Design", and choose background style, mouse over on an item

[image]

- Or another menu like this:

[image]

Comment: Some of the ribbon controls have onChange events that might give you what you're after.  Highly recommend "RibbonX" by Martin/Puls/Hennig if you need to do much with the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg, The book that you suggest is great, that's what I am looking for.